# unity Plastic SCM error every time I try to checkin

Tags: unity-game-engine, error-handling, plasticscm

so I just downloaded plastic scm for my unity project today and whenever I try to checkin my changes (I have made a lot of progress on the game, so my guess is that the mass checkin is the problem) I get this error saying: "this is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server" for completely no reason, if you know how to stop this from happening, please answer my question

1- [Plastic SCM error whenever I try to checkin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lCGN.png)

2- [Full Window screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lscL0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time that error is related with network issues (Slow, unstable, high latency), you might want to consider a distributed workflow in that case: https://www.plasticscm.com/book/index.html#_centralized_distributed

A workaround is to checkin smaller chunks at a time until everything gets uploaded.